# Spring-Security: Sending SAML2 Logout request leads to session lost in SAML-Server

Tags: spring-security

We're moving from out own SAML implementation to Spring Secuity's SAML implementation in Spring Boot 4 (Spring Security 6). Sending the `Saml2LogoutRequest` leads to a session loast error in the SAML2-Server (a simpleSamlPhp instance in my test scenario), and the logout is not performed. Reloading the page creates a new session in the background, since the user is only logged-out from the SpringBoot application.

What I found debugging the issue is the following:

POSTing to the logout-Endpoint leads to `LogoutFilter.doFilter()` being called, and the user is logged-out of the system, as shown in the log:

```
2023-02-21T16:19:24.369+01:00 DEBUG 897328 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /sso/saml/logout
2023-02-21T16:19:24.371+01:00 DEBUG 897328 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=AiToolSaml2Authentication [Principal=org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.DefaultSaml2AuthenticatedPrincipal@669175a9, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=73598BB643535D6256B71F961AFF7266], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_CONSUMER]]]
2023-02-21T16:20:09.065+01:00  WARN 897328 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=48s315ms980µs301ns).
2023-02-21T16:20:10.414+01:00 DEBUG 897328 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Logging out [AiToolSaml2Authentication [Principal=org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.DefaultSaml2AuthenticatedPrincipal@669175a9, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=73598BB643535D6256B71F961AFF7266], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_CONSUMER]]]
2023-02-21T16:20:16.845+01:00 DEBUG 897328 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.l.SecurityContextLogoutHandler : Invalidated session 348DCC90A54531D2C855906B14A6F8E4
```

After that, `Saml2RelyingPartyInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler.onLogoutSuccess()` is called, and a `Saml2LogoutRequest` is generated. This request is redirected to the SAML2 server via `doRedirect()` in that very method.

I can see the request in the SAML server's enpoint 'SingleLogoutService.php', after that resumelogout.php` is called which fails stating state information lost as described [here](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.18/simplesamlphp-nostate).

The request itself looks OK as far as I can see, I also checked SameSite=None and Secure=1 are set in the SAML cookie.

In our own implementation we used to have a GET request to logout redirecting to the SAML server which works fine using the same SAML configuration. The `Saml2LogoutRequest` needs to set Issuer, NameID, ID and IssueInstant, the only thing to override was NameID, which I do via an `Saml2LogoutRequestResolver`.

I'm not sure what exactly fails, and I'm also not sure if it is the pre-log-out in the SpringBoot-App, that causes the problem.

Any thoughts?

The current test-config looks like this (http only on localhost, our testing-environment uses https; the error is identical, though):

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          saml:
            assertingparty:
              entity-id: "http://localhost:8000/saml2/idp/metadata.php"
              metadata-uri: "http://localhost:8000/saml2/idp/metadata.php"
              singlesignon:
                url: "http://localhost:8000/saml2/idp/SSOService.php"
            entity-id: "http://localhost:8080"
            singlelogout:
              url: "http://localhost:8000/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php"
            signing:
              credentials:
              - certificate-location: "classpath:saml.crt"
                private-key-location: "classpath:saml.key"
```

The security config looks like that:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity, registrations: RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository): SecurityFilterChain {
    ...
    // saml (sso) login
    http.saml2Login { saml2LoginConfigurer ->
        saml2LoginConfigurer
            .authenticationRequestUri("/sso/{registrationId}/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl(samlResponseUrl.replace("{baseUrl}", ""))
            .authenticationManager(ProviderManager(samlAuthenticationProvider()))
            .defaultSuccessUrl(samlRedirectUrl)
            .failureUrl(samlRedirectUrlNewUser)
        }
    // saml (sso) logout
    http.saml2Logout { saml2LogoutConfigurer ->
        saml2LogoutConfigurer
            .logoutUrl("/sso/saml/logout")
            .logoutRequest { request ->
                request.logoutRequestResolver(
                    logoutRequestResolver(DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver(registrations))
                )
            }
        }
    ...
    }

    @Bean
    fun samlAuthenticationProvider(): OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider =
        // provider configuration
        OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider().apply {
            setResponseAuthenticationConverter { responseToken: OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.ResponseToken ->
                val authentication = OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider
                    .createDefaultResponseAuthenticationConverter()
                    .convert(responseToken)
                val principal = (authentication!!.principal as DefaultSaml2AuthenticatedPrincipal)
                val email = principal.attributes[samlEmailAttributName]
                check(email != null) { "Configured email attribute not found in SAML response." }
                check(email.size == 1) { "Configured email attribute is not unique." }
                check(email[0] is String) { "Configured email attribute value is not a string." }
                val user = (authenticationService.loadUserByUsername(email[0] as String)
                AiToolSaml2Authentication(
                    user,
                    principal,
                    authentication.credentials.toString(),
                    user.authorities
                )
            }
        }

    @Bean
    fun logoutRequestResolver(
        registrationResolver: RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver
    ): Saml2LogoutRequestResolver =
        OpenSaml4LogoutRequestResolver(registrationResolver).apply {
            setParametersConsumer { parameters ->
                with(parameters.logoutRequest) {
                    nameID.value = parameters.authentication.getUserInternal().user.email
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This whole thing turned out to be a CORS problem. Setting Access-Control headers correctly and allowing credentials to be CORS-submitted in the client fixes the problem.